# web2py - sqlite3 -> "_lazy_tables" error

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I try to make this database in a def

```
database = DAL('sqlite://userhistory3.db')
database.define_table('userjob', Field('UserID'),Field('JobID'))
session.database=database
```

but when I try to insert a value in another def

```
sd=session.database     
sd.userjob.insert(UserID=auth.user_id,JobID=job_Id)
database.commit()
```

I got the error 'DAL' object has no attribute '_lazy_tables'.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve a `DAL` (database connection) object from the session, it will only work if you first reconnect with the same connection string -- something like this:

```
database = DAL('sqlite://userhistory3.db')
sd=session.database
```

But the retrieved connection won't have any table definitions, so it won't be useful for your purpose.

In general, you should not need to store the `DAL` object in the session. Just put the `DAL` creation and table definitions in a model file, and it will be available for all requests -- no need to keep saving and retrieving from the session.

Also, there is no reason to call `db.commit()` within the application code -- committing is done automatically at the end of the request.